# How to stop iTunes auto starting and playing when a phone call comes in with BT headphones

Tags: iphone, mac, bluetooth

I get a phone call on my iPhone which is paired with QC35 headphones. At the point that the call starts, my mac starts iTunes and starts to play music through the same headphones I'm taking the call on.

I've tried disabling iTunesHelper but this continues to occur. Completely ridiculous out of the box behaviour.